# How to query the same Firestore data in multiple React components efficiently?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose that in my app, several components fetch the same data from Firestore: they fetch the documents of the same collection with the same filters and limits.

The app has 3 pages, 2 of them render the components that need the firestore data (the red nodes: AA and D). Page 2 does not need the data:

[image]

If I duplicate the `query.onSnapshot` in AA and D, does the Firestore JS SDK hold a global cache or does it fetch the data twice?
Should I put the query in the first common ancester, ie Router, at the expense of loading data even if only Page2 is used?
What is the best way to implement this?

## Edit: Precision

I know that we can fetch the data in the first common ancestor and pass it down with prop drilling, redux, or React.Context. This is not the point of my question.
I am specifically asking in the context of fetching **Firestore** data: since there exist a cache (for offline or cache first query), is there a trick to allow querying the data only if needed, and only once?

Comment: If you are using redux in your app you can store data in a reducer and use it wherever you need

Comment: This is by definition the ideal use case for a React Context

You can use context to fetch the data once in, say, App.tsx and setting it there.
Then, each one of your child components can use something like ``` <FirestoreContext.Consumer> ``` to access the data

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thank you for your answers, indeed we can pass data down from the top with redux for Abhi, or React.Context for diego92sigma6, or prop drilling, but that is not the point of my question. I have added this precision.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an empty state of data in router and write a logic to fetch the data in a function in router which after fetching updates the data in state.

```js
// in router.js
const [data, setData] = useState(null)

const fetchData = () => {
    const apiResponse = getResponseFromAPI()
    setData(apiResponse)
}
```

Pass this state and function as prop to AA and D component.

In the useEffect of AA and D check if data is present then don't call the function

```js
// in AA component
useEffect(() => {
    if(!data){
        fetchData()
    }
},[])
```

In this way you will only fetch the data when its necessary and it will be fetched only once

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a crude way of what I am trying to achieve. But we need to take care of data races: what if AA starts to fetch, the D is mounted before AA as finished fetching? We need to manage a "querying", "success", "error" states. I am asking if there is a better way using the Firestore SDK.